# Hibernate on non-managed environment

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I got an small problem, I always worked with Hibernate and Spring on Web stuff with a GenericDAO pattern, now I'm using Hibernate for a GUI app which doesn't use anything like EJB and stuff.

My main problem is I used to have this

`@PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit")
private EntityManager em;`

but now I do thing this way:

`private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
    private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();`

Just came to notice a big flaw I have is that whenever I inherit this GenericDAO class I'm creating one EntityManagerFactory each time, what should I do?

EDIT:

Agree this would be the neatest way to solve it?

```
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
private static final Connector INSTANCE = new Connector();

public static Connector getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}   

private Connector(){        
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
}

public EntityManagerFactory getEmf() {      
return emf;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use dependency injection pattern without Spring or other container - create `EntityManagerFactory` in a single place and inject it into DAO objects when you create them.

Comment: Something like a singleton that provides me one EntityManagerFactory on each call?

Comment: @JavaNoober: I mean that at some point you need to construct your DAOs. If you make this point centralized, you can set `EntityManagerFactory`s there. Almost like Spring, but without Spring.

Comment: ok, got ya, but what I did worked fine, people is already complaining that they have to begin and commit transactions, trying to keep all the DB side away from the developers